# What's the difference between height and maxY, and width and maxW?

Tags: ios, height, width, core-graphics, cgrect

From the Apple Documentation, the maxY of a view is

> The largest value for the y-coordinate of the rectangle.

The maxX of a view is

> The largest value of the x-coordinate for the rectangle.

Also from the Apple Documentation, the width of a view is

> The width of the specified rectangle.

The height of a view is

> The height of the specified rectangle.

If the view being specified took up the whole screen, then what would be the difference between these properties, and when should I use each?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They are the same when the origin is 0,0 but quite different otherwise.

Imagine the `CGRect` with x: 10, y: 30, width: 15, height: 40

Obviously `width` is `15` and `height` is `40`. But `maxX` is `25` and `maxY` is `70`.

Basically, `maxX` is `origin.x + width` and `maxY` is `origin.y + height`.

The above assumes a "normal" rectangle with a positive width and height. When you have a negative width or height, the calculation for `maxX` or `maxY` are a little different.

Comment: rmaddy, I have a question. By the 'origin', you mean the origin of the view controller, or the view itself?

Comment: Only a view has a frame.